# What is the history and regional dispersion of the affirmative "yup"?

Tags: etymology

Living in the Pacific Northwest, a person I'm close to frequently uses this word instead of the more common "yep" or "yeah". As I haven't heard it regularly from others and she has Southern American roots, I wondered what the source of this word is and what geographic regions it's most common.

My limited searching of several dictionaries and some Google searches gave a variety of origin years ranging from the early 1900s to the 1980s. None of them cited this first usage and I was unable to find information on on regional distribution at a sub-national level; apparently this is primarily an Americanism, though this was not well cited either.

Comment: ***Etymology of affirmations: yes, yea, yeah, yep, aye | OUPblog.*** http://blog.oup.com/2014/12/etymology-affirmations-yes-yea-yeah-yep-aye/

Comment: Yes is the same word as yea which is the same in germanic. It's a very old word. Being one of the most used words in the English language, yea probably was said as yep and yup in many colloquial settings, workshops, pubs many times before it was recorded in writing. yup is a fairly low energy way of say the word, which is probably easier to pronounce than yea, so laborers saying yea would have probably said yep/yup even centuries ago, in the year 1200!!! same as saying nope, it's a lazy pronunciation made likely by repetition. leap and chop are easier to say than lea and cho.

Comment: As far as "regional dispersion" goes, *yup* is certainly widely used in Britain.

Comment: In the US, I'd consider "yup" to be rural, but not necessarily attached to a particular culture.

Comment: @DeltaEnfieldWaid *Yes is the same word as yea which is the same in Germanic.* This somewhat misleading. 1. **Yes** was formed in English, and "**yea**" in Germanic. 2. "**Yea**" (and "**Nay**") is distinctly different in meaning to Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sources suggest its origin (1906) as an variant of yep which is used mainly in  the west part of the U.S.A.

***[Yup](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yup)***:

> - form of yeah as an isolated or emphatic utterance, with p representing closing of the lips, creating, in effect, an unreleased labial stop (and perhaps also lowering the vowel); compare the parallel use of p in nope.

(Dictionary.com)

***[Yep vs yup](https://www.quora.com/Slang-What-is-the-difference-between-yep-and-yup)***:

> - The difference is one of intonation and accent, not any difference in meaning.  Originally, the two spellings would have stemmed from regionalisms, "yep" in the East and Southern USA, "yup" in the West.

(Quora.com)

***[Yup](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wc/from-yea-and-yes-to-yeah-and-yup/)***:

> - The Oxford English Dictionary places the first use of yeah in 1905, one year before yup. Although the first quotation for yup comes from a magazine article, the first quotation for yeah is from an academic journal on American regional dialects.
> - It's likely both words were in use before they showed up in print, so the best presumption we can make is that yeah and yup appeared around the same time.

Here's the timeline:

> - Yep, 1891 (first appeared as a quotation in Harper's Magazine)
> - Yeah, 1905 (first described in Dialect Notes)
> - ***Yup, 1906 (first appeared as a quotation in Century Magazine)***

(www.visualthesaurus.com)

Comment: I had found the dictionary.com origin but wasn't satisfied since they didn't indicate where this was used in 1906. Thanks for narrowing it down to Century Magazine. You did a great job tying together the multitude of (often poor) sources out there to paint a clearer picture.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the US distribution of *yup, yep, yeah* and *yea* according to [the great American word mapper](http://qz.com/862325/the-great-american-word-mapper/#int/words=yup_yep_yeah_yea&smoothing=3): "Where the top 100,000 words are used the most, as seen through Twitter data".

[image: yup, yep, yeah, yea on the US map]

We can see *yup* is most popular in the north, north-east, but also Texas and the mid-west.

Of these four, *yeah* is most popular in the Pacific north-west.

Comment: This answer is a wonderful compliment to @JOSH's great answer. Thank you for fleshing out where it's used and for turning me on to such a good resource.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman You're welcome! Do the maps tally with the usage you've heard?

Comment: I don't think I can judge unless these charts use a constant scale; I've spent nearly all my life in the PNW and these charts really only allow region to region comparison of a single phrase. A similar chart that shows the relative popularity of each word in one region would be all I can speak to.

Answer (score 1):

Growing up in the 80’s in Chicago *Yup* was a derogatory way to agree disrespectfully to a teacher or one you disliked...often it was said *Yuuuup!* to emphasize the disdain one felt for the receiver, yet attempting to agree.  We were encouraged to use *yes* if we wanted to show respect and manners.  My husband grew up in the 70’s and does not recall using *Yup* among his friends and in school. We grew up a few miles from each other and different decades of course. I am curious if anyone else experienced something similar?

I do not recall *yep* having the same stigma. *Yep* came later in my life and to us it seems like a casual way to say *yes* to a close friend.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Kim! I think I've heard _YuuuuUP!_ used disrespectfully that way in a recording somewhere. I was from PA. Do give some time to take the [tour] if you haven't yet. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I remember both ways of response "Yuuuup!" Or "Yop!" Was used to show disdain, annoyance or to show you didn't care about the situation you were responding to.

Generally, it was used by children with other children as a normal response.

i.e. Do you care about getting to school on time?  Yuuup! (Hates the effort and would rather not try)

Did you make Dana fall flat on her butt?  Yop! (And could care less)

Comment: Hi Trina, yep, this would benefit from more information.  Who is your "we" is a start for a reference on occasion (where, when).  Please do take a look at the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope I figured out the missing word but if not you can always click on [edit].

Answer (score 1):

With regard to early occurrences in print of "yup" as an informal conversational way of saying "yes," I note the following instances uncovered in a series of Elephind newspaper database searches that I ran for the period 1880–1890.

From "[In the Far West: A Frontier Justice Who Believes in the Enforcement of Good Laws](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038161/1886-09-29/ed-1/seq-6/#words=%22yup%22)," in the *[Hillsboro, Ohio] News-Herald* (September 29, 1886), reprinted from the *Chicago [Illinois] Rambler*:

> A man with his face bandaged up, walking on crutches, limped into the office of a justice of the peace in Red Gulch, Arizona, last week, and exclaimed: "Do you know Two-fingered Jimmy?"
>
> "**Yup**," responded the justice.
>
> "Well, I want a warrant for his arrest!" continued the lame man, excitedly.

From "[Pronunciation of 'Yes,'](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87076917/1887-11-05/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22yup%22)" in the *Springfield [Ohio] Daily Republic* (November 5, 1887), reprinted from *The Youth's Companion* (published in Boston, Massachusetts):

> There is probably no word in the English language which is more ruthlessly corrupted in the pronunciation than this monosyllable. A party of young people were saying goodbye on the corner of a street in Boston.
>
> "May I walk with you?" asked a young man of a charmingly pretty and fresh girl, "Shall we cross the common?"
>
> "Ayah!" was the nonchalant reply. At least this is as nearly as the pen can do justice to the sound. It is to be presumed that the pretty young lady meant "yes," for she and her companion immediately set off in the direction indicated, but no foreigner would have guessed that the correctly written affirmative and her corruption of it were one and the same.
>
> There are many versions of this one little word, from the "**Yup**" of the street boy to the inarticulate grunt of the boor, yet, after all, the combination of three letters is not difficult to pronounce.

From "[Bottles and Rags: A Thanksgiving Story](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth293981/m1/2/zoom/?q=%22yup%22&resolution=3&lat=5050&lon=911.5)," in the *Dallas [Texas] Daily Herald* (November 23, 1887), reprinted from *Commercial Travelers' Magazine*, also published in Boston:

> "Bottles," said the girl [Rags], after a short pause, "what's the most money you ever had in all yer life?"
>
> "To onct, do you mean, Rags?"
>
> "**Yup**."

Bottles and Rags are described in the story as "Boston street waifs."

From "[The Thoughts of Youth Are Long](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90059522/1888-11-04/ed-1/seq-13/#words=%22yup%22)," in the *St. Paul [Minnesota] Daily Globe* (November 4, 1888), reprinted from *Puck*:

> It's papa's birthday next week, Johnny," remarked Mamma, "and you ought to be thinking of giving him a present."
>
> "Yairp," said Johnny.
>
> You hadn't forgot it, had you?"
>
> "Yop."
>
> "Then you hadn't thought of any thing to give him?"
>
> "Nawp."
>
> "Let's see. You've saved up $2 haven't you?"
>
> "**Yup**."

I suspect that *Puck* in this case refers to the U.S. humor magazine of that name, which was originally published in St. Louis, Missouri, but relocated to New York City by 1887.

From "[Wise Men](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn93067777/1888-12-20/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22yup%22)," in the *Newberry [South Carolina] Herald and News* (December 20, 1898):

> "Done be'n hunt'n, Uncle Eph'm?" asked the one [hunter] with the game of the other, who hadn't any.
>
> "**Yup**, Rufus," said Uncle Ephraim.
>
> "Yah! Aint done tuk nuffin, eh?"

From Alice Brown, "[A Tricycle Story](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85032490/1889-07-05/ed-1/seq-7/#words=%22yup%22)," in the *Wichita [Kansas] Eagle* (July 5, 1889), reprinted from *The Youth's Companion*:

> "Has your father a horse?" called Daphne to a bareheaded and barefooted boy who sat on the fence, gazing at us in what we hoped was admiring awe.
>
> "**Yup**."
>
> "Is he at home the horse, I mean?"
>
> "No, he ain't."

And from "[Among the Corn Rows: An Interesting Romance of a Dakota Settler](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1890-07-05/ed-1/seq-7/#words=%22yup%2Bsaid%22)," in the *[Washington, D.C.] Evening Star* (July 5, 1890), reprinted from *Harper's Weekly*, which was published in New York City:

> Rob [Rodemaker] looked over the edge of the bank, whistled, turned away. "Oh, I see! Excuse me! Don't blame yeh a bit, though. Good weather f'r corn," he went on, looking up at the trees. "Corn seems to be pretty well forward," he continued in a louder voice as he looked away, still gazing into the air. "Crops is looking first-class in Boomtown. Hello! Is this Otto? H'yare, y' little scamp! Get on to that horse ag'in. Quick, 'r I'll take y'r skin off an' hang it on the fence. What y' been doing?"
>
> "Ben in swimmin'. Jimminy, ain't it fun! When 'd y' get back?" said the boy, grinning.
>
> "Never you mind," replied Bob, leaping the fence by laying his left hand on the top rail. "Get on that horse." He tossed the boy up on the horse, hung his coat on the fence. "I s'pose the ol' man makes her [Julia] plough the same as usual?"
>
> "**Yup**," said Otto.

Otto is a boy named Otto Peterson, the little brother of Julia, the story's heroine, and the son of Norwegian immigrants to the Dakotas.

---

***Assessment***

The seven instances cited in this answer appeared in U.S. newspapers during a period from September 1886 to July 1890, indicating that the expression was in use in some parts of the United States by the latter half of the 1880s. Although the earliest relevant instance of "yup" was first published in Chicago, Illinois, its writer claims (unconvincingly) that the anecdote originated in what was at that time still the relatively Wild West of Arizona—and the speaker to whom the word is attributed is a justice of the peace.

Five of the remaining six instances, however, come from publications in either Boston (three) or New York (two). The only other place of origin of a unique instance of "yup" in the relevant sense during this period is Newberry, South Carolina, in a newspaper anecdote in which it appears as a dialect word.

All five of the Boston and New York instances associate the expression with children, including two Boston instances that specifically link its use to street waifs. Whether "yup" as "yes" originated in the northeastern U.S. and among children is unclear from this tiny sample of occurrences, but it certainly seems to have been in use among children there from a fairly early stage of its published existence.

I should note that instances of "yup" as a nonsense syllable or as a sound for calling to various domesticated animals (from dogs to horses to pigs) go back to the 1850s at least, but I see no necessary connection between these uses of "yup" and "yup" as a form of "yes."