# "Yeap" and "yep" and "yeah"

Tags: word-usage, dialects

Is the use of "Yeap" and "yep" and "yeah", more predominant in different English speaking countries, or is it more a matter of personal preference?

**UPDATE:**  The motivation for my question is not for a scientific study (I am an engineer by trade). The question was on the "spur of the moment", after replying to a comment in another SE forum. There was an exchange of "yeap" and "yep" and I merely wanted to know if that is indicative of the country of origin.

I haven't conducted any research on the matter, I wanted the perspective of native English speakers (I am not an native English speaker).

Given that the question originated on a written forum, I am more interested in how people write the words.

Comment: Are you asking about what people say, or are you asking about what people write? Is this a survey of opinions, or are you asking about scientific data? What has your research discovered about this so far?

Comment: You could also include "yup", "yuppers" and "ya" into the mix, all of which would serve as a fine way of saying "yes" for an illiterate boor.

Comment: @tchrist my apologies for not being more explicit on the motivation of my request.  I 've updated the question, hopefully in a manner that makes it possible to reply.

Comment: I've never seen "yeap" as a transcription of an affirmative, so I'm not sure how it's supposed to sound. I sometimes see "yea" in places where I would have written "yeah".

Comment: I've never seen "yeap" either and have no idea how to pronounce it. **NMech** can you cite an example?

Comment: @BeginnerBiker I've even seen "yeppers."

Comment: I would be very careful in using any of these terms in place of yes in written form, unless you intend to sound crass.

Comment: @greybeard This is not something I've seen it written in a formal letter or text. The example that prompted me to post the question is in the comments of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226516/what-is-the-name-of-a-de-with-this-form).  It is very informal.  I would say, that's its basically putting down in writing the casual thing one would say.

Comment: This question discusses yeah, yup and yep, but not "yeap" which seems a solecism. Does this answer your question? [What is the history and regional dispersion of the affirmative "yup"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362782/what-is-the-history-and-regional-dispersion-of-the-affirmative-yup)

Comment: @StuartF, yes I think this is probably very close to what I was asking. It is somewhat limited to UK and US, however, I think it is enough to satisfy my curiosity. After all, I realized after posting that my question is more a matter of opinions rather than stone cold facts.